# Apply bulk CSS using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I do not want to have to manually do $("#element").css('attr','val'); since I have a lot of elements.  The following illustrates what I am trying to do but is not properly working.  It is a PHP file but the PHP is irrelevant:

```
<?

     $css1 = "
              #ele1 { border: 1 px solid blue; }
              #ele2 { border: 1 px solid blue; }
            "; 

     $css2 = "
              #ele1 { border: 1 px solid black; }
              #ele2 { border: 1 px solid black; }
            "; 


?>

<html>
  <head>
    <style id="appliedCss"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    ....... PAGE HERE .....
    <script>
       $("#btn1").click(function (e) {
             $("#appliedCss").html(<?=$css1?>);
       });

       $("#btn2").click(function (e) {
             $("#appliedCss").html(<?=$css2?>);
       });
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use a class? This is exactly what they're for.

Comment: you could use `text()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$('.more-than-one-element').css('name', 'value');
```

or

```
$('#element').css({
    'name1': 'value1',
    'name2': 'value2',
    ...
});
```

or (but be careful with this way, it append the whole styles to the styles-attribute in HTML)

```
var cssText = $('#element').css('cssText');
cssText += 'name1: value1, name2, value2, ...';
$('#element').css('cssText', cssText);
```